# Bridge Ethernet and Firewire

Tags: 12.04, networking, ethernet, network-bridge, firewire

I'm trying to connection between my eth0 and firewire0 interfaces on an Ubuntu 12.04 server. I tried using brctrl, but it apparently doesn't support firewire:

```
samuelwn@master:~$ sudo brctl addif br0 eth0 firewire0
can't add firewire0 to bridge br0: Invalid argument
```

The firewire connection itself is configured properly and works fine (I can SSH through it), but I'm wondering if anyone out there knows of a way to bridge ethernet and firewire. I searched through Google and couldn't come up with anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not bridge a firewire. From http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bridge

> Does it work with Token Ring , FDDI, or Firewire?
>
> **No, the addressing and frame sizes are different.**

You would need to work around this with route or NAT.

There are several possibilities, see http://adterrasperaspera.com/blog/2011/08/05/linux-layer-2-bridging-cant-do-firewire/ and  http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/bridge-wireless-cards/